# Form Always prompting to update

Tags: 2010, infopath, updatepanel

I have a form (2007 filler form template - deployed on SharePoint 2010, opens in infopath) and when it opens I am always getting a prompt saying a 'new version is available and to update the form'. Does anyone know a possible cause and/or fix for this as I am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking on the prompt to update the form? Give this a try. I am not entirely sure how InfoPath pulls forms down from the server but, it may have a cache that stores copies of these forms.

Comment: Yes, once I update the form updates and runs fine. The problem is that I get this everytime the form is opened and the form needs to be updated. I figured this would be a caching problem - would this be a server side cache or user sided?

Comment: My guess would be user. Could be an problem if you are using InfoPath Filler 2007 trying to commuincate with SP 2010